# jQuery Resizable : Unique MinWidth for each element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jQuery UI Resizable with draggable and droppable. Once element is dropped, I need to control the min width (different sizes for each element) while resizing.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/rxnqjoa2/1/)

> **Requirement**

- **Text element : Min width should be 100px**
- **Button element : Min width should be 50px**

[image]

In below I am able to control same min-width for all the elements, but not differently.

Tried below code without success :(

```
if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput text')) {
    $element.appendTo(this);
    $element.append(textElement);
    $(this).resizable({
        minWidth: 100,
    });
}
else if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput button')) {
    $element.appendTo(this);
    $element.append(buttonElement);
    $(this).resizable({
        minWidth: 50,
    });
}
```

Comment: You should set the `minWidth` option within the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
var $element = ui.helper.clone();
$element.resizable().draggable().selectable();
$element.appendTo(this);

if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput text')) {
  $element.append(textElement);
  $(this).resizable("option", "minWidth", 100);
} else if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput button')) {
  $element.append(buttonElement);
  $(this).resizable("option", "minWidth", 50);
}
```

Here you can see where youset the option after it has been initialized. See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minWidth

Comment: **@Twisty**, Thanks for the **perfect** answer. I am **ACCEPTING** and **UPVOTING** your awesome answer. Thanks a ton